# How can I select replace file automaticaly in cmd?

Tags: windows-7, windows-command-prompt

How can I select replace file automaticaly in the command prompt?

I am trying to run the following command:

```
schtasks /create /tn "Restart Ingenico" /tr "C:\IT_Dept\RestartShift4.bat" /sc daily /st 07:30 /y
Pause
```

When I do this, I get the following error message:

```
Invalid argument/option - "/y". Type "schtasks /create /?" for usage
```

Comment: What do you expect with `/y` ? It is not an available switch for `schtasks `. What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: /Y I guess should work as confirmation option

Comment: Confirmation for what ? Guessing is a thing, supported switches are another : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: ok my mistake cmd see /y as a Syntax. But I need switches. In winXP xcopy command goes with switche /y (/y : Suppresses prompting to confirm that you want to overwrite an existing destination file.)

Comment: I have an error message even If i type

schtasks /create /tn "Restart Ingenico" /tr "C:\IT_Dept\RestartShift4.bat" /sc daily /st 07:30

 /y

Comment: Where /y is in another line

Comment: Ironically, the answers is already in the question: `Type "schtasks /create /?" for usage`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to overwrite the task if it's already there, use the `/F` switch.

The switch is also explained in the `schtasks /Create /?` help and [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744.aspx#BKMK_syntax).